# Bootstrap Modal Not Displaying, outputs JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal setup with the following code:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Testimonials</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Test Text Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btns btn-3 btn-3g btnsx" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">More</button>
```

However, I am getting only a black background when clicking the button.

I am also seeing some of my js appearing at the bottom of my page (only when the modal code is inserted):

```
.on('submit', function() { var form = $(this); var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php $('#loader').html('loadng Please Wait...'); $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'http://shazconstruction.com/test/process.php', // Your form script data: post_data, success: function(msg) { $('#loader').html(''); // We know this is the form that needs fading in/out $('form#contactUs').fadeOut(500, function(){ $('form#contactUs').html(msg).fadeIn(); }); } }); return false; }); });
```

Here is the site where everything exists:
http://bit.ly/1dbf4Rz

For reference, this is the section with the modal setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sDpg.png

Comment: If you look at the source code you'll see that you have the script in plain text format and you closed body and html two times, you may have pasted it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source of your page. However it's being generated has a pretty clear error: http://screencast.com/t/GZv0KwPktoO

Look at line 762. There is no opening script tag, so that would explain why you're seeing your JS appearing at the bottom of the page.

As for the rest of it, BaBL86 is right, you will want to fix the issue with your mousewheel script as it's throwing errors that cause the page to stop rendering JS.

Once those two issues are fixed, let us know if there are still problems.

Edit: You also have incorrect HTML for your modal window (based off the bootstrap 3 documentation). Try using this instead, and moving your modal window to right after the body tag:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Test Header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Test Text Here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your mousewheel function. Check this answer, it's about this problem:

```
function handler(event) {
    < ---- >
    return $.event.handle.apply(this, args); // error here
}
```

Edit your function to:

```
    return $.event.dispatch.apply(this, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given `!important` to `.hide`. Remove the `imporant`

From this

```
display: none!important;
```

To

```
display: none;
```

I can also see that you are not giving any `background-color`. Use the same code from `bootstrap`